# charles debugging not working

Tags: https, charles-proxy

I want to test requests and responses from servers.
Iam using ubuntu and python programming language.
I have checked charles debugging tool, in some research came to know that java is to be installed.I have installed java but charles debugging tool is not working.
Is this tool can be checked in ubuntu? 
can any one give me some clear idea of this tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is some info tucked away in the Charles documentation, have a look at http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/

> JAVA APPLICATION PROXY CONFIGURATION
>
> You can configure your Java application to use Charles in code or as
>   command line arguments to the java executable.
>
> System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
>   System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
>
> And for HTTPS as well. Note that you may also want to configure Java
>   to trust Charles’s root certificate in this case (see SSL Proxying).
>
> System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
>   System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
>
> For the source of this information, including more discussion and how
>   to set these as command line arguments:
>   http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/proxies.html
>
> Also see this tutorial on integrating Charles with your Java
>   application by a Charles user.